# Why isn't Time.deltaTime equal to the sum of element.deltaTime in all the elements of Input.accelerationEvents?

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer

`Time.deltaTime` gives you the time passed in the last frame.

`Input.accelerationEvents` contains an array of the last reads of the accelerometer and its time.

I'd guess that after

```cs
totalTime = 0;
foreach (AccelerationEvent element in Input.accelerationEvents){
    totalTime +=element.deltaTime;  
}
```

the result would be equal to Time.deltaTime, but it isn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AccelerationEvent.deltaTime` variable returns the amount of time since the last sampling of the device's accelerometer. However, this sampling is not guaranteed to be synchronized with game framerate (even though both aim to achieve 60Hz), and as such the sum of the `deltaTime` of all `Input.accelerationEvents` during a frame may not equate the `Time.deltaTime` of that frame.

The [the Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html) mentions something to this effect:

> [...] In reality, things are a little bit more complicated – accelerometer
>   sampling doesn’t occur at consistent time intervals, if under
>   significant CPU loads. As a result, the system might report 2 samples
>   during one frame, then 1 sample during the next frame.

One way to visualize this is with the following (assume each dash is one arbitrary unit of time):

```
Frames completed:
1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6-----7-----8-----9-----

Accelerometer samples made:
1-----2-----3-----4------5-----6---7-----8-----9-----
```

Note that while `frame6` is being completed, both `sample6` and `sample7` were made. However, although `frame6.deltaTime` = 5, the sum of `sample6.deltaTime + sample7.deltaTime` = 5 + 3 = 8. As a result, their times don't match up.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what they say in Unity documentation regarding accelerometer http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html

> Unity samples the hardware at a frequency of 60Hz and stores the result into the >variable. In reality, things are a little bit more complicated – accelerometer >sampling doesn’t occur at consistent time intervals, if under significant CPU >loads. As a result, the system might report 2 samples during one frame, then 1 >sample during the next frame

Also don't forget that

> AccelerationEvent.deltaTime is Amount of time passed since last accelerometer measurement. 
>   And Time.deltaTime is the time in seconds it took to complete the last frame.

Those values are independent and there is no reason for them to be equal to each other.